d3js - geojson of polygons is not drawn
I'm trying to draw a map (polygons of the districts of a city) using d3js. And all I get is a beige rectangle.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lpgz crime rates</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #map {
            width: 800px;
            height: 600px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        .map path {
            stroke: #999;
            stroke-width: 0.5;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <svg id="map" viewBox="0 0 800 600"></svg>
    <script>
        const width = 800;
        const height = 600;
        const margin = 20;

        const svg = d3.select('#map')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height);

        Promise.all([
            d3.json('data/Leipzig_ortsteile.geojson'),
            d3.json('data/crime_rates.json')
        ]).then(([ortsteile, crimeRates]) => {
            console.log("GeoJSON data:", ortsteile.features);
            console.log("Crime rates data:", crimeRates);

            const projection = d3.geoMercator()
                .fitSize([width, height], ortsteile);

            const pathGenerator = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

            const colorScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateReds)
                .domain([0, d3.max(Object.values(crimeRates))]);

            const paths = svg.selectAll('path')
                .data(ortsteile.features)
                .enter()
                .append('path')
                .attr('d', d => {
                    const pathData = pathGenerator(d);
                    console.log(`Path data for ${d.properties.Name}:`, pathData);
                    return pathData;
                })
                .attr('fill', d => {
                    const rate = crimeRates[d.properties.Name];
                    console.log(`Area: ${d.properties.Name}, Crime rate: ${rate}`);
                    return rate ? colorScale(rate) : '#ccc';
                })
                .attr('stroke', '#999')
                .attr('stroke-width', '0.5');

            console.log("SVG Paths:", paths);

        }).catch(err => console.error("Error loading data:", err));
    </script>
</body>
</html>

This is how the geojson looks like inside:
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "log_lat",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "FID": 0, "OT": "00", "Name": "Zentrum" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 12.37927526130802, 51.344360566287889 ], [ 12.379117566590359, 51.344399728002436 ], [ 12.378953533569369, 51. ....

I tried multiple variations including centering at the coordinates of the city center, changing sizes... I get no errors and outputs to the console look ok (to me).

Sounds like a winding order issue, you can rewind with turf or rewind manually - though the latter option can miswind any features that are properly wound. You'll probably want to save the json afterwards and use that rather than processing every map load. I believe mapshaper.org offers a rewinding command (-clean rewind) as well.

@AndrewReid thank you for your comment! I tried rewinding with the mapshaper.org but nothing changed...

I may have erred in including mapshaper as an option - D3 uses a contrary winding order to the geojson spec (though ironically, the geojson spec also states 2D coordinates and consequently inside outside is implied and therefore winding order doesn't matter. D3 is one of the few tools to treat coordinates as 3D points on a globe where winding order does matter, but goes contrary to the geojson spec on the winding direction - but I digress), so Mapshaper might actually not wind them right. However, I may have missed something else, can you share the geojson at all?

@AndrewReid I added the file here: https://github.com/iurshina/lpz_crime/blob/master/data/Leipzig_ortsteile.geojson It should be something with D3 because it looks ok everywhere else... (but I'm a backend person and have very little experience with js and geodata, it could be something very stupid...)

The issue is winding, your code is otherwise fine.
I apologize that my comment included a reference to mapshaper - this service corrects the winding, whereas D3 requires it to be incorrect. I included it as the service is user friendly and doesn't require any code (and also is generally D3 friendly) unlike the other two verified options. But I had never used it before.
Your file will work in almost every other mapping/plotting framework as these treat latitude longitudes as planar. A consequence of this is winding order does not matter for these frameworks: for a polygon the outside is always the portion that is unbounded and the inside is bounded.
For D3, the latitude longitudes are on a globe, so there is no unbounded portion. The whole screen is the same color as the last feature drawn covers the entire globe except for the desired area. FitSize consequently fits the entire globe.
One option to verify that your geojson is incorrectly wound is to manually set the projection to zoom in on your area of interest and remove any fill, you should generally see the outline of all your features (If your features are all gibberish, then you have another problem, you're projecting already projected data).
Below I have a complete example of using Turf to rewind, realizing that my linked example isn't quite complete.
<html>
<head>
    <script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@6.5.0/turf.min.js "></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>

d3.json("target.json").then(function(data) {
    
    var fixed = data.features.map(function(feature) {
        return turf.rewind(feature,{reverse:true});
    })
        

    data.features = fixed;
    
    d3.select("body").append("p")
      .text(JSON.stringify(data));
    
})
</script>

